# How to change a value placed inside a array in a json object in json array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, iteration

I am using javascript to perform this.

I want to change `[0,0,1]` to `[3,0,1]` where `id = 'a'`.

```
[
 {'id' : 'a', arr : [0,0,1]},
 {'id' : 'b', arr : [1,0,1]},
 {'id' : 'c', arr : [1,4,1]}
]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Use [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to get matching object and mutate `arr` property, or (if immutability is required) use [`Array.prototype.findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) to find the index of matching item, then rebuild source array (from its shallow copy) with target item modified, or use `Array.prototype.map()` with all the items unchanged except the one with matching `id`.

Comment: `mArr=[
 {'id' : 'a', arr : [0,0,1]},
 {'id' : 'b', arr : [1,0,1]},
 {'id' : 'c', arr : [1,4,1]}
];`
`mArr.forEach(item=>{if(item.id=="a") item.arr=[3,0,1]; return item;});`

Comment: @iAmOren : if to choose between mutating approaches, I would prefer `.find()` - it will exit the loop once the match is found letting you to mutate its output, while `.forEach()` will iterate unnecessarily till the end of source array, which may happen to be relatively large.

Answer (score 1):

```
    You can have few different approach to achieve this
    1. using Map
        
  let tmp = [
    {'id' : 'a', arr : [0,0,1]},
    {'id' : 'b', arr : [1,0,1]},
    {'id' : 'c', arr : [1,4,1]}
   ]
   var updated_array;
   updated_array = tmp.map(function(element){
       if(element.id == 'a'){
         return {
          id: element.id,
          arr : [3,0,1]

          }   
       } else {
         return element
        }
   })
    
    2. Using Filter

   updated_array = tmp.filter(function(element){
    if(element.id == 'a'){
      return {
       id: element.id,
       arr : [3,0,1]

       }   
    } else {
      return element
     }
})

    3. Using ForEach


tmp.forEach(function(element){
          if(element.id == 'a'){
            element.arr = [3,0,1]
          }
        }) 


    4. You can also use traditional while or for loop to achieve this
```

Answer (score -1):

Try like this

```
let value =[
    {'id' : 'a', arr : [0,0,1]},
    {'id' : 'b', arr : [1,0,1]},
    {'id' : 'c', arr : [1,4,1]}
   ]
   value.forEach(val=>{
   if(val.id=='a'){
    val.arr=[3,0,1] 
   }
})
```

Comment: That's not proper use of `Array.prototype.map()`, which is expected to return the array. To simply loop through the source array, you're supposed to use `Array.prototype.forEach()`

Answer (score -1):

You can use map() of the array and update the value. Check below code.

```js
let tmp = [
 {'id' : 'a', arr : [0,0,1]},
 {'id' : 'b', arr : [1,0,1]},
 {'id' : 'c', arr : [1,4,1]}
]

tmp.map(item =>{
 if (item.id === 'a'){
  item.arr=[3,0,1];
 }
})

console.log(tmp);
```

Comment: Using `.map()` for mutating source array is a bit confusing, you'd be much better off with `Array.prototype.forEach()`

Comment: That threw me off too. "How is he using .map without returning anything?"

Comment: Another thing you should consider, that your approach is probably one of the least efficient among *non-immutable* - it will loop through the entire array to mutate the single item (which may appear, like in this case, right in the first position). For large enough inputs it may cause performance waste. As an alternative way, `Array.prototype.find()` may be used, which will exit the loop upon hitting the match, so you may use its output to mutate `arr` property.

Comment: ...and it wasn't mine downvote, just in case you rush for revenge ;)